# Add row and column total to gtsummary tbl_summary

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data-wrangling, gtsummary

I'm using `dplyr` and `gtsummary` to produce a cross table for multiple variables in the column using the following data:

```
# Generate data
set.seed(123)
member <- sample(c("Yes", "No"), 100, replace = TRUE)
author <- sample(c("Yes", "No"), 100, replace = TRUE)
review <- sample(0:10, 100, replace = TRUE)
publish <- sample(0:10, 100, replace = TRUE)
pay <- sample(0:10, 100, replace = TRUE)
data <- data.frame(member, author, review, publish, pay)
```

I tried used this code but what's missing is the column total

```
data %>%
  mutate(across(c(review, publish, pay), ~cut(., breaks = c(-Inf, 4.5, 5.5, Inf),
                                              labels = c("No", "Maybe", "Yes"),
                                              include.lowest = TRUE), .names = "{.col}_group")) %>% 
  select(member, author, ends_with("group")) %>%
  tbl_summary(
    by = member,
    missing = "no", 
    statistic = list(all_categorical() ~ "{n} ({p}%)"),
    digits = list(all_categorical() ~ c(0, 1))
  ) %>%
  add_p(test = all_categorical() ~ "fisher.test")%>% 
  add_overall() %>% 
  #add_n() %>% 
  bold_labels()
```

[image]

I just want to add the total for "overall", "No", and "Yes" below for each variable. I tried `tbl_cross` but id does not allow multiple variables in the column.

Comment: Have you seen the tbl_cross() function from gtsummary? It can easily add row and column totals

Comment: @DanielD.Sjoberg I tried tbl_cross but it appears to only take one variable for both row and column.

Answer (score 2):

It was not possible for me to add a total row in one `tbl_summary()`.
So I made another table for a total row, and merge two tables with `tbl_stack()`.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(gtsummary)
set.seed(123)
member <- sample(c("Yes", "No"), 100, replace = TRUE)
author <- sample(c("Yes", "No"), 100, replace = TRUE)
review <- sample(0:10, 100, replace = TRUE)
publish <- sample(0:10, 100, replace = TRUE)
pay <- sample(0:10, 100, replace = TRUE)
data <- data.frame(member, author, review, publish, pay)

tbl <- data %>%
  mutate(across(c(review, publish, pay), ~cut(., breaks = c(-Inf, 4.5, 5.5, Inf),
                                              labels = c("No", "Maybe", "Yes"),
                                              include.lowest = TRUE), .names = "{.col}_group")) %>% 
  select(member, author, ends_with("group")) %>%
  tbl_summary(
    by = member,
    missing = "no", 
    statistic = list(all_categorical() ~ "{n} ({p}%)"),
    digits = list(all_categorical() ~ c(0, 1))
  ) %>%
  add_p(test = all_categorical() ~ "fisher.test")%>% 
  add_overall() %>% 

  bold_labels()

tbl_total <- data %>% 
  select(member, author, ends_with("group")) %>%
  mutate(all_true = "Total") %>% 
  tbl_summary(
    by = member,
    include = all_true
  ) %>%
  bold_levels() %>%
  add_overall() %>%
  modify_table_body(
    ~.x %>% filter(row_type %in% "level")
  ) %>%
  modify_column_indent(columns = label, undo = TRUE) 

tbl_stack(list(tbl_total, tbl)) %>%
  as_kable() # only for showing the table in stack overflow
```

| **Characteristic** | **Overall**, N = 100 | **No**, N = 43 | **Yes**, N = 57 | **p-value** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Total** | 100 (100%) | 43 (100%) | 57 (100%) |  |
| **author** | 46 (46.0%) | 20 (46.5%) | 26 (45.6%) | >0.9 |
| **review_group** |  |  |  | 0.2 |
| No | 37 (37.0%) | 20 (46.5%) | 17 (29.8%) |  |
| Maybe | 7 (7.0%) | 3 (7.0%) | 4 (7.0%) |  |
| Yes | 56 (56.0%) | 20 (46.5%) | 36 (63.2%) |  |
| **publish_group** |  |  |  | 0.055 |
| No | 51 (51.0%) | 26 (60.5%) | 25 (43.9%) |  |
| Maybe | 8 (8.0%) | 5 (11.6%) | 3 (5.3%) |  |
| Yes | 41 (41.0%) | 12 (27.9%) | 29 (50.9%) |  |
| **pay_group** |  |  |  | 0.2 |
| No | 41 (41.0%) | 19 (44.2%) | 22 (38.6%) |  |
| Maybe | 9 (9.0%) | 6 (14.0%) | 3 (5.3%) |  |
| Yes | 50 (50.0%) | 18 (41.9%) | 32 (56.1%) |  |

<sup>Created on 2023-05-14 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks @yhjang for helping, but I wanted the total for columns of each group, so "No", "Maybe", Yes" for review_group and so on.